# how to add web site programmatically in Linux VPS?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, vps

I want to add a web site to a Centos VPS programmatically, I found many references to IIS, but nothing for Linux.

I have a site that lets the users create a customized web site. What I want is give the users the option to use their own domain.

So, when the user add his/her own domain (and point his/her domain to my DNS server) add this domain as an add-on domain to my server and also add a virtual host to apache....

any help will be appreciated...

Regards Alex

Answer (score 1):

Something like cPanel or ISPconfig ?

Comment: I need this to be programmatically, is there a CPanel API?

Answer (score 1):

You can install virtualmin and use their API via REST URL or run script remotely. It does mailboxes too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is simple. I've previously run a webfarm (using 1.3.27) with around 1000 vhosts configured on each server exactly like this - startup took a couple of seconds longer but otherwise there was little difference from a single vhost. Just specify a directory to contain the definitions for the vhosts (one per file) and set up a directory tree for each website. The machine I'm typing this at came with Apache 2.2 pre-configured to handle just such a case; in the httpd.conf there's a line:

```
Include conf/vhosts.d/*.conf
```

And the create a file, say example.com.conf containing:

```
 <VirtualHost example.com>
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 DocumentRoot /var/vhosts/example.com/www
 CustomLog /var/vhosts/example.com/logs common
 ErrorLog /var/vhosts/example.com/logs
 </VirtualHost>
```

You might want to create a user at the same time and point their home directory to the base locattion (/var/vhosts/example.com). I'd recommend disabling all cgi / shtml / php /symlinks etc unless you know how to configure these securely. Preferably allow override none too.

An alternative approach is to use a wildcard vhost with all requests routed to your front controller which would then invoke specific bits of functionality - but this requires rather a lot of development effort.

Comment: Thanks @symcbean, this is what I want. but is it possible to add the domain to my dns?

Comment: Yes - but you don't say what DNS server it is (I used bid and it was much the same process with an SOA record.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Bind
This is returned by # named -v
BIND 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-16.P1.el5_7.1